# Set colormap on scatter3 plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, scatter-plot, color-mapping

I am plotting a depth image (RGBD) as a scatter graph, using `scatter3(x,y,z)` in matlab.

How can I set a colormap on the scatter3 plot where the color is dependent on the z-value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually want a 3D-Visuasation?

Then use `scatter3` as follows:

```
scatter3(x,y,z,[],z)
```

where `[]` can be any number specifying the size of your circles, otherwise the default **36** is used.

If you just want to use `z` as definition for the color, use the simple `scatter`

```
scatter(x,y,[],z)
```

you can set the colormap as usual:

```
colormap(hot)
```

**Example:**

```
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(16);
x = [0.5*X(:); 0.75*X(:); X(:)];
y = [0.5*Y(:); 0.75*Y(:); Y(:)];
z = [0.5*Z(:); 0.75*Z(:); Z(:)];

scatter3(x,y,z,[],z)
colormap(hot)
```

[image]

[More information in the documentation.](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)